# Docx password verifier

Tags: java

I've a small programme in java that should verify a password but seems to be coming up short. IF anyone here has any experience with offcrypto the help would be greatly appreciated.

My main class is as follows.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.*;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.DigestException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil;
import org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndianConsts;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CipherAlgorithm;

import java.util.Base64;

public class KeyGen
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *       variables are extracted from docx in base64 format
        *
        *       then manually transformed to hex then byte array as per JtR
        *
        ***********************************************************************/
        String salt = "gqJkQH6pdKPLzLSvXzNk/Q==";//initial values retrieved from word doc
        String HashInput ="jjyuf6DaqqL81TLEovnr0w==";
        String HashValue="VZUku9tIkOMd2HyoF+Qq1E9wjmgaPvujUaauptYHxbtVpvvG4tfhbYg2vDJJFxo8V73DlAcWESDQyLlrD8/y3A==";//this was truncated in JtR but will only work at full length here

        String hexSalt="82a264407ea974a3cbccb4af5f3364fd";
        String hexHashInput="8e3cae7fa0daaaa2fcd532c4a2f9ebd3";
        String hexHashValue = "559524bbdb4890e31dd87ca817e42ad44f708e681a3efba351a6aea6d607c5bb";

        Hex h = new Hex();

        //hexSalt = h.hexToAscii(hexSalt);
        //hexHashInput = h.hexToAscii(hexHashInput);
        //hexHashValue = h.hexToAscii(hexHashValue);

        int spinCount = 100000;//loop count
        int blockSize = 16;
        int keySize = 32;//size in bytes = 256 bits
        String password = "abc";
        byte[] blockKeyInput = {(byte)0xfe,(byte)0xa7,(byte)0xd2,(byte)0x76,(byte)0x3b,(byte)0x4b,(byte)0x9e,(byte)0x79};//block key for input given by microsoft
        byte[] blockKeyValue = {(byte)0xd7,(byte)0xaa,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x6d,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x61,(byte)0x34,(byte)0x4e};//block key for value given by microsoft

        byte[] decodedValueIn = Base64.getDecoder().decode(HashInput);//decode base64 values to byte array
        byte[] decodedValueVal = Base64.getDecoder().decode(HashValue);
        byte[] decodedSalt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt);

        //decodedValueVal = hexHashValue.getBytes();
        //decodedValueIn = hexHashInput.getBytes();
        //decodedSalt = hexSalt.getBytes();

        SHA512 sha = new SHA512();//create sha object

        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *       variables used in cryptofunctions class parameters
        *
        ***********************************************************************/

        HashAlgorithm ha = HashAlgorithm.sha512;//define hash algorithm
        CipherAlgorithm ca = CipherAlgorithm.aes256;//define encryption algorithm
        ChainingMode cm = ChainingMode.cbc;//define chaining mode
        int cipherMode = 0;//unused as cryptofunctions class code changed
        boolean iteratorFirst = true;//order of i (i+hash)

        CryptoFunctions cf = new CryptoFunctions();//call class instead of using library (for troubleshooting)

        byte[] hash = cf.hashPassword(password,ha,decodedSalt,spinCount,iteratorFirst);//get hash from loop

        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *   generate an IV (initialization vector) for each key generated
        *
        ***********************************************************************/


        byte[] IVIn = cf.generateIv(ha,decodedSalt,blockKeyInput,blockSize);//get IV from salt+blockKey
        byte[] IVVal = cf.generateIv(ha,decodedSalt,blockKeyValue,blockSize);

        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *       generate final byte arrays which are part of the key
        *
        ***********************************************************************/    

        byte[] valueKey = cf.generateKey(hash,ha,blockKeyValue,keySize);
        byte[] inputKey = cf.generateKey(hash,ha,blockKeyInput,keySize);//as above
        SecretKeySpec inKey = new SecretKeySpec(inputKey,"AES");//generate key for cipher parameter
        SecretKeySpec valKey = new SecretKeySpec(valueKey,"AES");//generate second key

        Cipher cipherV = cf.getCipher(valKey,ca,cm,IVVal,cipherMode);//get cipher from combined values
        Cipher cipherI = cf.getCipher(inKey,ca,cm,IVIn,cipherMode);

        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *       final step decrypt two values then hash input
        *
        ***********************************************************************/

        byte[] decryptedIn = {};//initialize byte arrays outside try/catch
        byte[] decryptedVal = {};
        byte[] hashedBytesIn = {};

        try
        {
            decryptedIn = cipherI.doFinal(decodedValueIn);//do final decrypts using aes256+key
            decryptedVal = cipherV.doFinal(decodedValueVal);
            hashedBytesIn = sha.hashBytes(decryptedIn);//input must be hashed again
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}

        /**********************************************************************
        *
        *       compare arrays to retrieve candidate key result
        *
        ***********************************************************************/

        boolean Result = Arrays.equals(hashedBytesIn,decryptedVal);

        if(Result)//check for matching values
        {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Fail!");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("decryptedVal"+Arrays.toString(decryptedVal));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("hashedBytesIn"+Arrays.toString(hashedBytesIn));     
    }

}

    /****************************************POSSIBLE ERRORS********************************************
    *
    *           No padding found in docx so field is empty in CryptoFunctinos.getCipher()
    *
    *           Secret Key is used in cf but in this class its SecretKeySpec, can't instantiate SecretKey
    *
    ****************************************************************************************************/
```

The encryptedVerifierHashInput and encryptedVerifierHashValue are both stored in the encrypted document, I've just hard coded them for the time being. These are both decoded, then decrypted using the derived key and the input value is hashed again. They should both match to confirm the password. Unfortunately they do not.

I thought I had it cracked but there's a problem in there somewhere and I'm hoping someone here might spot it.

The cryptofunctions class is from the library here.

http://source.dussan.org/raw/mirrors/poi.git/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/

Comment: Your code has missing imports for classes `Hex` and `SHA512`. Where are those classes from?

Comment: `Hex` is not important, as I see that it is actually not used. Another thing: this line is bothering me - `int cipherMode = 0;//unused as cryptofunctions class code changed` - does that mean you use changed `CryptoFunctions` class? If so, where do I get it (the link in the post leads to an unchanged version from Apache POI). And please otherwise check that you provided a complete compilable code example.